# Custom search for product custom post type

Tags: wordpress, search, custom-post-type

I have prepared a custom post of products. I want to include a form with few filters for search. As I am doing search for firsttime. my product template is different and want to show its result within the page or in specific div. how is it possible. I am a bit confuse. following are my form fields.

```
<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">Search Keyword:</div>
                <div class="col-md-3"><input type="text" placeholder="Search Product..."></div>
                <div class="col-md-2"><input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Searchi"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <lable for="r1"><input type="radio" name="product-filter" id="r1" checked="chcecked"> Any Words</lable>
                <lable for="r2"><input type="radio" name="product-filter" id="r2"> All Words</lable>
                <lable for="r3"><input type="radio" name="product-filter" id="r3"> Exact Phrase</lable>
            </div>
            <em>Search term must be a minimum of 3 characters and a maximum of 20 characters</em>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pass the custom post type slug in hidden

like post type name : products

```
<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink(1) ); ?>">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3">Search Keyword:</div>
                    <div class="col-md-3"><input type="text" placeholder="Search Product..."></div>
                    <div class="col-md-2"><input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Searchi"> <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="products"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <lable for="r1"><input type="radio" name="product-filter" id="r1" checked="chcecked"> Any Words</lable>
                    <lable for="r2"><input type="radio" name="product-filter" id="r2"> All Words</lable>
                    <lable for="r3"><input type="radio" name="product-filter" id="r3"> Exact Phrase</lable>
                </div>
                <em>Search term must be a minimum of 3 characters and a maximum of 20 characters</em>
            </form>
```

Comment: http://www.graymarkdesigns.com/ssa/product-directory/  this is my page... i've placed the code back in template file. and added a search.php file. but when i submit it it direct me to home page

Comment: change the action
<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?> to <?php echo get_page_link('product-directory'); ?>

Comment: is there any possiblility that i get the resul below the form.. i mean my 'products-template.php' page will show the search result and once i click on any result it take me to its detail page?

Comment: what is your page id ?
add your page id in place of 1
<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink(1) ); ?>

Comment: i have added script above. let me know if i am doing something wrong

Answer (score 0):

following is the code of search form as per your guidance.

```
<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>">
    <label>        
        <span class="screen-reader-text">Search for:</span>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search Product...">
        <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search">
        <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="product">
    </label>
</form>
```

following is the search result below the form

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<h2 class="page-content-title">Search results for: <?php echo get_search_query(); ?></h2>
<div class="container">
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<div class="blog-page-content">
<?php if (has_post_thumbnail()) : ?>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_id, 'medium', array( 'class' => 'img-responsive' ) ); ?></a>
<?php else : ?>
<?php endif; ?>
    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="category-title-link"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
    <h6 class="article-meta-extra">
        <?php if (has_category() && !has_category('Uncategorized')) : ?>
            <?php the_category('  |  '); ?> |  
        <?php else : ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
        Posted on <?php the_date(get_option('date_format')); ?> at <?php the_time(get_option('time_format')); ?> by <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?>
    </h6>
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="btn btn-blue btn-block">Read More</a>
</div><!-- END EACH BLOG-->
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php else : ?>
<article class="no-posts"><h1>No posts were found.</h1></article>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
<div class="article-nav clearfix">
<p class="article-nav-next pull-right"><?php previous_posts_link(__('Newer Posts »')); ?></p>
<p class="article-nav-prev pull-left"><?php next_posts_link(__('« Older Posts')); ?></p>
</div>
```

the problem is it always show the result. my custom post name is 'product' without s.

Comment: what is your custom post type? product or products? and what is your page id of "product-directory" page. go to admin-> pages-> edit "product-directory" and copy the page id of browser url.

Comment: product without S is my custom post

Comment: I just simply place on index page, result shows below form within the page

Comment: change the form action <?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?> to <?php echo esc_url( get_permalink(your product-directory page id) ); ?>

Comment: there is no product directory.

Comment: what is this url "http://www.graymarkdesigns.com/ssa/product-directory/"?

Comment: its a page which layout structure to show form 'layouts/products-template.php' and below form I want to show the result of search form. it take me to some other page

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147133/discussion-between-shital-marakana-and-john-paul).